# How to supply cookie to Java HTMLDocument?

Tags: java, cookies, dom

I'm trying to read a web site as an HTMLDocument; and the site requires either a cookie from a previous logon, or a response to a popup dialog.  I'm thinking that supplying the necessary cookie is the easiest to accomplish, but I haven't found a way to do that.  The code to open and read the document is:

```
URL url = new URL(suppliedURL);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback callback = htmlDoc.getReader(0);
parser.parse(br, callback, true);
```

The retrieved document contains incorrect information that can only be corrected by invoking a logon dialog or supplying a cookie.

So the questions are:

1. How do I supply a cookie when opening this page?
2. How do I copy the information from an existing IE cookie to the cookie I supply?

Answer (score 3):

How about using [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html).

Comment: I don't think I can use Apache.  I'm looking for a Java solution. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Yes, its a Java project. Did you look into it. It has some examples, and a general tutorial as well. Find the tutorial link on the left menu of that page.

Comment: HttpClient is a library for accessing http in java - the apache you are familiar with is actually the apache httpd, or http daemon, the web server. dont get them confused.